# como puedo filtrar un datagridview en c# y buscar todo los campos a partir de una caja de texto

Tags: c#

eso lo vi en mysql Workbench
agradezco cualquiera comentario
adjunto foto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluí que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Por favor deja más detalles. No quedó claro que necesitas hacer. Por ejemplo, cual es el dato que quisieras buscar en tu tabla, y donde quisieras mostrar ese listado.

Answer (score 0):

Pero que trataste de hacer?
Te dejo una manera de hacerlo

```
public DataTable Datos(string nombre)
{
       string query = "SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE nombre=@nom";

       using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("CadenaConexion"))
       {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom",nombre);
                MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adap.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
       }
}
```

Como ves creas un metodo que retorna una datatable apartir de un dato a filtra.

Luego para cargar los datos arias asi.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Datos(TextBox1.Text);
```

Llenas el datagrid con los campos filtrados enviando como argumento el dato del Textbox.